# ContextMenu in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, contextmenu, expandablelistview, childviews

hi frnds in my application i use expandableListView. an i need to integrate a contextMenu for the expandable listView. in my expandable ListView i inflate different layouts for different child. so when i do a long click on each childView i need to perform different action.

here i gives the code for ContextMenu.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info=
            (ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
    int type=ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);
    Log.e("type",""+type);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
    menu.add(1, 1, 1, "Edit");
}
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();

    if(item.getItemId()==1)
    {
        Log.e("clickd","menu");
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

and in my onCreate() i register the listView forContextMenu.

```
registerForContextMenu(expListView);
```

but when i press on the GroupView it desplay the contextMenu. but when i click on the childView it doesn't shows the ContextMenu.. pls help me.....

Answer (score 3):

Use this one it worked for me.
After setting your adapter to Expandable ListView write it.

```
setListAdapter(expListAdapter);
            registerForContextMenu(getExpandableListView());
```

Answer (score 2):

You have also to set the view to be long clickable in `getChildView(...)` of your Adapter.

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ... 
    convertView.setLongClickable( true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

in your ExpandableListViewAdapter